# Adding text in images

Tags: graphics, image-processing

My question is simple

How can I add text in a figure like the following?

[image]

In particular I want two labels: one at the top "Label text 1" ()just above the image and one at the right side (just outside), written vertically "Label text 2". Of course, I must be able to control the font family, size, etc of the labels.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want to label the image or you want the text to be inside the image ?

Comment: @Lotus The first label should be just above the image and the second one just outside the right side.

Comment: Try the function Labeled then.

Comment: Labeled[img, {"Top Text", "Right Text"}, {Top, Right}]. You can use Rotate, Style etc..to style accordingly

Comment: @Lotus That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! Could you please post a quick answer, so as to accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Labeled[img, {"Top Text", "Right Text"}, {Top, Right}]
```